# divs floated left with hidden overflow in container with width 100%

Tags: html, overflow

Here is the code:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:200px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid red;" id="container">
<div style="float:left;width:400px;height:100px;border:1px solid green;" class="inner">
first div</div>
<div style="float:left;width:400px;height:100px;border:1px solid green;" class="inner">
second div</div>
<div style="float:left;width:400px;height:100px;border:1px solid green;" class="inner">
third div</div>
</div>​
```

How I can make that divs with class inner to stay in line if screen height is smaller then 1200px? That code show divs one below other if screen height is smaller then 1200px.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
   #container { width: 400px; height: 300px; }
}
```

Use media queries.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WzwrP/), note that inline styles will override external CSS, so I had to move the `#container` style.

Comment: Can I find fix for IE7 & IE8 & and Safari for working with css3 and @media?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've hardcoded your width of your inner divs with width:400px.

You need to set them to percentages... and in your .inner class, preferably.

```
.inner {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

You could also add a min-width to .inner if you want to keep them from shrinking too much, and combine it with bookcasey's comment about @media queries to make it more flexible at smaller sizes.

Comment: I want fixed width of div with class inner 200px.

Comment: You can't constrain the outer width of your container and expect floated elements to simply ignore their container. Now, if you want them to disappear, you'll have to contain them in a container with a fixed width, set to the combined width of all your inner divs. That way, they will all float next to each other, within the context of their container, but their container will disappear where it exceeds the width of the outermost container. See this jsFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/wpdKe/

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to add

```
position: relative;
```

on the outer container - and then put

```
position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
```

on the 'inner' containers. Then you can control them the way it sounds like you want to. It's important to put 'position: relative;' on the outer container, since the inner containers need something to be absolute to... If that makes sence. I hope it helps.